# if statement, boolean value

Tags: c#

This method is taken from Murach's C# 2010 book and is given as an example of an method that checks if a string contains a decimal value:

```
        // the new IsDecimal method
    public bool IsDecimal(TextBox textBox, string name)
    {
        //make sure the string only contains numbers and numeric formatting
        string s = textBox.Text;
        int decimalCount = 0;
        bool validDecimal = true;
        foreach (char c in s)
        {
            if (!(
                c == '0' || c == '1' || c == '2' ||   // numeric chars
                c == '3' || c == '4' || c == '5' ||
                c == '6' || c == '7' || c == '8' ||
                c == '9' || c == '.' ||
                c == '$' || c == '%' || c == ',' ||  // formatting chars
                c == ' '
                ))
            {
                validDecimal = false;
                break;
            }
            if (c == '.')
            {
                decimalCount++;
            }
        } // end loop

        if (validDecimal && decimalCount <= 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(name + " must be a decimal number.",
                "Entry Error");
            textBox.Focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

My question is about this if statement and boolean value:

```
            if (validDecimal && decimalCount <= 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
```

I understand that it should be checking if both validDecimal returns true from above loop and that there is only one decimal point present. I'm quite confused by this, my understanding of bool is that it can hold two values: 1 = true and 0 = false; in both of those cases that if statement would be satisfied (0 is smaller than 1 and 1 is equal). I'm thinking that correct if statement would look something like that: if (validDecimal == true && decimalCount <= 1) but since I'm beginner I'm not sure and this isn't in the errata for this book.

Comment: My eyes are bleeding on this code. I hope Murach never put this into production. What's being taught here? The art of spaghetti-craft? I'll have $%%%$,,%.%$$$ please.

Comment: @spender any c# books you do recommend?

Comment: That would very much depend on the level at which you are trying to learn and your background/education, and what you are hoping to get out of it. If you feel like you're learning from this (it sounds like you are), stick with it. I'm probably not the best person to ask as the books I'd recommend would IMO be difficult for a beginner, but I've often found OReilly books to be well edited and informative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `bool` value on its own is the same as `value == true`

If you have

```
bool trueThing = true;
```

then the following are all equivalent (and true)

```
trueThing;
trueThing == true;
(trueThing == true) == true;
((trueThing == true) == true) == true;
```

and so on.  The simplest, least verbose form is the first: trueThing.  It's not a 0 or 1, it's a true or false.

Comment: Thank you, now it makes perfect sense.

Comment: +1 Put another way, `&&` is a boolean operator and `validDecimal` is a boolean.

Answer (score 3):

Operator Precedence.  This:

```
if (validDecimal && decimalCount <= 1)
```

is interpreted as:

```
if (validDecimal &&  (decimalCount <= 1))
```

not

```
if ((validDecimal && decimalCount) <= 1)
```

In other words, the `<=` happens before the `&&`.

Comment: And even if it meant that, it wouldn't be legal. You can't apply `&&` to `bool` and `int`.

Comment: @svick, Depending on the compiler, you can.  It's only a warning with VC++.  And with SunStudio, I once came across code that performed addition similarly (if memory serves, it was of the form `int += bool`).

Comment: Your third example is confusing, and wont compile either.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're reading the statement wrong, if you placed parentheses, so that it's obvious what's going on, it would look like

```
(validDecimal) && (decimalCount <= 1)
```

not

```
(validDecimal && decimalCount) <= 1
```

In English: check that `validDecimal` is `true` and `decimalCount` is at most 1. The comparison against `true` is implicit, because it's not necessary.

In C#, variable of type `bool` can have one of two values, `true` or `false`, but they don't act as numbers, so you can't say they are 1 and 0 (although they are usually implemented that way).

Also, in most languages, if you mean “`a` and `b` are both at most `x`”, you can't write it as `a && b <= x`. That's just not how (most) computer languages work.

Comment: thank you, was just confused because I haven't seen boolean written this way(declared as true)

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
if (validDecimal == true && decimalCount <= 1)
```

but it is equivalent to the shorthand way

```
if (validDecimal && decimalCount <= 1)
```

When the type is a bool no need to again use

> == true

as it is assumed

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know in c#, but in Java, you can even do this:

```
boolean b = 1<2;
```

`1<2` is true (remember, it's a boolean equation), so the value assigned to `b` is true. Everything you put in the if, is interpreted as

```
if(whateverLogicEquationHereIsTrue){do this}
else{means that the boolean input to the if, has come to be false}
```

now, what is the output of this?

```
if(!(1>2)){print "a"}
else{print "b"}
```

hint: `!` is the logical operator `NOT`